# Converting C++/CLI ref parameter to raw pointer

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, ref

I am trying to convert a bool ref parameter (.NET/C++CLI) to a bool* raw pointer to use in a native function.

**Native class with raw pointer parameter**

```
#pragma once
public class SampleClass
{
public:
    SampleClass(void);
    ~SampleClass(void);
    void DoWork(bool *cancel);
};
```

**C++/CLI wrapper class for .NET usage.**

```
#pragma once
public ref class SampleClassNet
{
public:
    SampleClassNet(void);
    void DoWork(bool% cancel);
};
```

**The .NET implementation of DoWork is as follows. NOTE: IT DOESN"T BUILD/WORK**

```
void SampleClassNet::DoWork(bool% cancel)
{
    SampleClass *sampleClass = new SampleClass();
    sampleClass->DoWork(cancel);
}
```

**Question**

How do I pass my ref boolean parameter from my C++/CLI class, into my native class that requires a raw bool* pointer to the ref parameter?

I need to be able to use &cancel in the native method to determine if we should stop an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
void SampleClassNet::DoWork(bool% cancel)
{
    bool cancelParam = cancel;
    SampleClass *sampleClass = new SampleClass();
    sampleClass->DoWork(&cancelParam);
    cancel = cancelParam;
}
```